# Firebase Data Loading Speed

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an android app using Firebase back-end. Everything works fine, I have no problem whatsoever. The only problem is that, the data loading speed. Because it's a cloud-based system, sometimes it takes 4-5 (or even longer) seconds to load a user profile picture or simply to pull username from the database to display user. Now, you might say, well we don't even know how your data structure is stored in the no-SQL table but really I can't go wrong with that. I just structured it in a way that it's just a simple one read query. Or is it normal? Maybe Firebase loads data with some delay.

How you as other developers, get over this loading time? For example, I have a user picture, where the pic should be loaded from the Firebase database, but till pic is loaded, the image-view is just staying as a black view.

Answer (score 0):

All of this depends on several factors that you can check.

- Internet speed
- Programming type
- The size of the files (you probably need a lot of time to load for a
  high volume file)

And another solution is to store the information you've previously received into the phone's memory[(cache)](https://medium.com/@coreflodev/make-an-easy-offline-working-android-application-fdbf1d679710).